Issue with session and object relationships extracting all data from a table instead of just one element
I've been trying all possible solutions suggested by chatgpt and what I could find on the web but nothing worked, and I think it's beyond my understanding of Python/Flask/SQLAlchemy.
I attempt to link products selected by the user and add this link to a product group (via a relationship association). I first query the database to make sure that one of the selected products isn't already linked. If all products are not linked, then I create a new group with the products' reference. If a product is already linked to a group, I add the other selected products to that group. My issue is that all products from the database are inadvertently being added to the group, not just the ones specifically selected.
More precisely, this is when the program hits the following line of code that suddenly, all the products are added to the 'existing_group' var: product = Product.query.get(product_id)
I've tried session.begin(), expunge(), direct SQL query code, and much more, but nothing worked. If you have any tips on how I could solve this issue, I'd be very appreciative! Thanks!
This is my main function that links products together:
@app.route('/link_products', methods=['POST'])
def link_products():
  product_ids = request.form.getlist('product_ids')
  # Split the string into a list of individual product IDs
  product_ids = [
      int(id.strip()) for id in product_ids[0].split(',') if id.strip()
  ]

  if len(product_ids) < 2:
    flash('Please select at least two products to link.', 'error')
    return redirect(url_for('feed'))

  # Check if any of the selected products belong to an existing group
  existing_group = ProductGroup.query.filter(
      ProductGroup.products.any(Product.id.in_(product_ids)),
      ProductGroup.user_id == current_user.id
  ).first()

  if existing_group:
    print(f"Existing group found: {existing_group.id}")
  else:
    # Create a new group if no existing group is found
    existing_group = ProductGroup(name="Group", user_id=current_user.id)
    db.session.add(existing_group)
      
  # Manage products within the session context
  existing_product_ids = [product.id for product in existing_group.products] if existing_group else []

  for product_id in product_ids:      
    if product_id not in existing_product_ids:
      product = Product.query.get(product_id)
      if product:
          # product = db.session.merge(product)
          existing_group.products.append(product)
          print(f"Appended product id: {product_id}, product name: {product.name}")
    
  db.session.commit()

  # Return the matched products as JSON response
  top_level_product = None
  matched_products = []
  if existing_group:
    top_level_product = Product.query.filter_by(id=existing_group.products[0].id).first()
    matched_products = Product.query.filter(Product.id.in_(existing_product_ids)).all()
  else:
    top_level_product = Product.query.filter_by(id=product_ids[0]).first()
    matched_products = Product.query.filter(Product.id.in_(product_ids)).all()

  return jsonify({
      'top_level_product': top_level_product.serialize(),
      'matched_products': [product.serialize() for product in matched_products]
  })

Here is my database model:
lass ProductGroup(db.Model):
  id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(primary_key=True)
  name: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.String(140))
  user_id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(sa.ForeignKey(User.id), index=True)

  user = relationship("User")

  products = relationship("Product", secondary="product_group_association", back_populates="groups")

  def __repr__(self):
      return f'<ProductGroup {self.name}>'


product_group_association = Table('product_group_association', db.Model.metadata,
                                sa.Column('group_id', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('product_group.id')),
                                sa.Column('product_id', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('product.id'))
                                )


class Product(db.Model):
  id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(primary_key=True)
  brand: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.String(140))
  name: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.String(140))
  description: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.String(400))
  price: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.String(32))
  timestamp: so.Mapped[datetime] = so.mapped_column(
      index=True, default=lambda: datetime.now(timezone.utc))
  location: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.String(140))
  user_id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(sa.ForeignKey(User.id), index=True)
  entry: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.String(140), nullable=True)
  photo_name: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.String(140), nullable=True)
  
  groups = relationship("ProductGroup", secondary="product_group_association", back_populates="products")

  def serialize(self):
    return {
        'id': self.id,
        'brand': self.brand,
        'name': self.name,
        'description': self.description,
        'price': self.price,
        'location': self.location,
        'timestamp': self.timestamp,
        'user_id': self.user_id,
        'photo_name': self.photo_name
    }
  
  def __repr__(self):
    return '<Product {}>'.format(self.name)


existing_group.products.append(product) You're calling this in a loop for each result of product = Product.query.get(product_id), so yes, all the products are added to existing_group, because that's what you told it to do...

product_ids contains only the ids of the products selected by the user. I've checked that the ids are correct and that only the ones from the products selected by the user end up here. So when I loop through this list, I'm supposed to only fetch the products (by their id) that were selected by the users, not all the products in the database. But as soon as the program hits this line 'product = Product.query.get(product_id)', and if I do a print() just after, all the products from the database are in existing_group. Hope this additional context helps. Thanks!
